# saltstack jinja for loop in parallel

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack, orchestration

hope to find you well and healthy :)

I have one jinja loop which is working, unfortunately not the way I would like :|

Short story:

Using salt-run for orchestration, minion targeting is accomplished by passing the pre-defined nodegroup as a pillar

```
{% set minions = salt.saltutil.runner('cache.mine', tgt=nodegroup,tgt_type='nodegroup').keys() %}
{% for minion_id in minions %}

patch-n1-{{ minion_id }}:
  salt.state:
    - tgt: {{ minion_id }}
    - sls:
      - patching.patch-n1
    - pillar:
        minion_id: {{ minion_id }}

reboot_minion-{{ minion_id }}:
  salt.function:
    - name: cmd.run_bg
    - arg:
      - 'salt-call system.reboot 1'
    - tgt: {{ minion_id }}

{% endfor %}
```

The problem is that with this loop both tasks are executed minion by minion. In my case, this is not efficient ...

If remove the loop both states are applied however again doesn't help so much.

Main goal is to apply patch-n1-{{ minion_id }} and reboot_minion-{{ minion_id }} for each minion in the nodegroup indipended from each other.
Or said in a different way I need a for loop which to work simultaneously for all minions in it.

Do you have any ideas about that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we target minions by *globbing*, or nodegroups, the defined states will be applied to them in parallel. So one way to achieve this is by moving the "reboot minion" functionality into the state file `patch-n1.sls` itself.

Example `/srv/salt/patch-n1.sls` file:

```yaml
# Some tasks to perform patching, just using 'include' for example
# from /srv/salt/patching/os_pkg.sls
include:
- patching.os_pkg

reboot-after-package-update:
  module.run:
  - name: system.reboot
```

And in orchestrate `/srv/salt/orch/patch_all.sls` file:

```yaml
patch-group1:
  salt.state:
  - tgt: group1
  - tgt_type: nodegroup
  - sls:
    - patch-n1

patch-group2:
  salt.state:
  - tgt: group2
  - tgt_type: nodegroup
  - sls:
    - patch-n2
```

When we run the orchestration, the each minion will run patching and reboot in parallel.

Comment: Hello seshadri_c, thank you for your suggestion.
but my problem is when I start the patching via nodegroup all minions members are patching simultaneously but they are not rebooting until all minions are not patched.

I would like to patch each system in the nodegroup and reboot them.
For example, if minion-1 is completed with the updates to reboot himself regardless of that minion-2 is still patching.

Comment: Now when I run the orchestration minions reboot will happen only when the last minion is complete with the updates

Answer (score 1):

system.reboot didn't help at my case bacause my minions are mixed (Windows, Linux)

```
reboot-after-package-update:
  module.run:
  - name: system.reboot
I was able to achieve my goal by:
```

```
# Some tasks to perform patching, just using 'include' for example
# from /srv/salt/patching/uptodate.sls

include:
- patching.uptodate

reboot-after-package-update:
  cmd.run:
    - name: shutdown -r -t 60

{% set stage = pillar['stage'] %}

{% set nodegroup = salt['pillar.get']('nodegroup', 'PILLAR nodegroup NOT FOUND!') %}

{% set minions = salt.saltutil.runner('cache.mine', tgt=nodegroup,tgt_type='nodegroup').keys() %}

wait_for_reboot-{{ stage }}:
  salt.wait_for_event:
    - name: salt/minion/*/start
    - id_list: {% for minion_id in minions %}
      - {{minion_id}}{% endfor %}
    - timeout: 6000
    - require:
      - cmd: reboot-after-package-update
```